# Git rebase and moving directory in submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-rebase

I have moved subdirectory in separate repository and then included it as submodule.

Now I want to rebase another branch on top of that change.

```
israfel:proj almad$ git rebase -i origin/master
error: could not apply ae1fd9a... Commit message
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' and run 'git rebase --continue'
Could not apply ae1fd9a... Commit message

israfel:proj almad$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   added by us:        views/docs/examples
#

israfel:proj almad$ git rm -rf views/docs/examples
views/docs/examples: needs merge
rm 'views/docs/examples'
fatal: git rm: 'views/docs/examples': Operation not permitted

israfel:proj almad$ git add views/docs/examples
error: unable to index file views/docs/examples
fatal: updating files failed

israfel:apiary almad$ git rm -rf views/docs/examples
views/docs/examples: needs merge
rm 'views/docs/examples'
fatal: git rm: 'views/docs/examples': Operation not permitted
```

How can I resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First call reset :

```
git reset views/docs/examples
git rm -rf views/docs/examples
```